# Determine logged on user on a remote Windows machine

Tags: windows, administration

Is there a way to determine who is logged on to a particular (remote) machine given the IP address (or the workstation name) of the machine?

- The machines in question are on an Active Directory Domain
- The user running the script probably won't have any special rights on either their local or the remote machine
- Operating system is Windows XP

Any programming language is fine but ideally

- VBScript (yeah I know)
- C#
- Java
- DOS Batch file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSloggedon from SysInternals will provide this from a batch file, however the user would require admin access on the remote machine. I doubt you can get this information without Administrator access.

Comment: +1 for any solution involving SysInternals apps.  Also, since there's an ActiveDirectory domain, you can allow this app to run for a group of people that you want to run the script (assuming you have rights to make those types of changes on the domain controller).

Comment: Sweet thanks, looks like PSloggedOn is what I need I'll test it with a non-admin user!

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to do depending on the permissioning on the machine. One way is to query WMI on the remote machine and check the owner of the explorer.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need admin access. Just use net apis.
ask on news://194.177.96.26/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32
where it's a FAQ